# How to go to the next grep result?

Tags: external-command

I'm using `grep` to find function occurrences in a project.

```
:grep "set_val" *
```

Goes out of vim and outputs:

```
code.py:68:        self._device.set_val('Level', new_level)
code.py:84:        self._device.set_val("Mode", "Remote")
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I press enter and am at `code.py:68` which is the first occurrence.

How do I move to other occurrences?

Comment: how about open the qf window?

Answer (score 33):

`:grep`/`:vimgrep` both use the quickfix list to store locations. As you have noticed vim will automatically jump to the first occurrence (use `!` to avoid this behavior). Simply use `:cnext` to go to the next location in the quickfix list.

#### Quickfix commands

- `:cnext`/`:cprevious` to navigate the quickfix forwards and backwards in the quickfix list
- `:cfirst`/`:clast` to jump to the start and end of the quickfix list
- Use `:copen` to open the quickfix window. Use `<cr>` to jump to an entry
- Use `:cclose` to close the quickfix window
- Use `:cc` to display the current error.
- `:colder`/`:cnewer` to jump older/newer quickfix lists

I would recommend you create mappings for `:cnext` and `:cprevious`. I personally use [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which provides `]q` & `[q` mappings for `:cnext` and `:cprevious`.

If you want the quickfix window to open automatically put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup autoquickfix
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* lwindow
augroup END
```

There is a [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode about this topic: [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/).

#### Project-wide Search and Replace

If you are using `:grep`/`:vimgrep` as way to do a [project-wide search and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/) then I suggest you use `:cdo`/`:cfdo` (in Vim 7.4.980+).

```
:grep 'foo'
:cfdo %s/foo/bar/g|w
```

If your version of Vim does not have `:cdo`/`:cfdo` put the following commands in your `vimrc` file to provide `:Cdo`/`:Cfdo` alternative commands.

```
if !exists(':cdo')
  command! -nargs=1 -complete=command Cdo try | sil cfirst |
        \ while 1 | exec <q-args> | sil cn | endwhile |
      \ catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E\%(553\|42\):/ |
      \ endtry

  command! -nargs=1 -complete=command Cfdo try | sil cfirst |
        \ while 1 | exec <q-args> | sil cnf | endwhile |
      \ catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E\%(553\|42\):/ |
      \ endtry
endif
```

#### Using an alternative program for `:grep`

Sometimes `grep` isn't quite good enough for your search needs. You can change your `:grep` program via the `'grepprg'` setting (may also need to change `'grepformat'` as well). Personally I use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) by adding the following to my `vimrc` file as instructed in `rg`'s man page:

```
set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
set grepformat^=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

Note: May want to use `-S` flag, e.g. `set grepprg=rg\ -S\ --vimgrep`, to use "smart case" searching (case insensitive searching when all lowercase letters).

Now `:grep` will use `rg` to search. e.g. `:grep foo -t js`.

Her are a few alternative grep programs to look into: [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), and [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) ([Fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) provides `:Ggrep` wrapper)

#### For more help see:

```
:h :grep
:h 'grepprg'
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :copen
:h :ccl
:h :cc
:h :colder
:h :cdo
:h :cfdo
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Your code for automatically opening the quickfix window works, but for me it opens and I have to then use commands to jump to it (ctr+w and down arrow). Can I add a line to automatically jump the cursor into the quickfix window after it automatically opens? Thank you. -Asaf

Comment: Using `:cwindow`/`:copen` inside the `QuickFixCmdPost` autocmd event will restore the current buffer after firing. You can add `:wincmd b` or whatever window command you want to the `autocmd`, but the window will be restored. This is alluded to in `:h autocmd-use`. If you think about it this behavior makes sense as you might have multiple autocmd's attached to an event, all of which have certain assumptions like the current buffer. I imagine the way to force the issue would be to wrap this into your quickfix command. e.g. `:command! Grep -nargs=+ grep <args> | cwindow`